# Why does calling glfwCreateWindow, then glfwTerminate, then glfwInit cause a segfault?

Tags: c++, linux, clojure, segmentation-fault, glfw

While playing around with repeatedly initializing and terminating [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/), I ran into a segfault. Here's a minimal C++ program that illustrates the problem I'm having:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
  glfwInit();
  // glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
  glfwCreateWindow(1, 1, "", NULL, NULL);
  glfwTerminate();
  std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
  glfwInit();
  std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
  glfwTerminate();
}
```

If I uncomment the call to `glfwWindowHint`, the program runs fine:

```
$ g++ glfw_segfault.cpp `pkg-config --static --libs glfw3`
$ ./a.out
before
after
```

However, without that call, I get a segfault:

```
$ g++ glfw_segfault.cpp `pkg-config --static --libs glfw3`
$ ./a.out
before
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Annoyingly, the segfault only happens some of the times that I run the above program. Other times, I get no segfault and the program runs exactly as I would expect. I also translated the above code into C and wasn't able to reproduce the segfault.

When I originally encountered this problem, I was using [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) and [Boot](http://boot-clj.com/):

```clj
#!/usr/bin/env boot

(set-env!
 :dependencies
 (let [lwjgl-version "3.0.0"]
   [['org.lwjgl/lwjgl lwjgl-version]
    ['org.lwjgl/lwjgl-platform lwjgl-version :classifier "natives-linux"]]))

(import (org.lwjgl.glfw GLFW)
        (org.lwjgl.system MemoryUtil))

(defn -main []
  (GLFW/glfwInit)
  ;; (GLFW/glfwWindowHint GLFW/GLFW_CLIENT_API GLFW/GLFW_NO_API)
  (GLFW/glfwCreateWindow 1 1 "" MemoryUtil/NULL MemoryUtil/NULL)
  (GLFW/glfwTerminate)
  (println "before")
  (GLFW/glfwInit)
  (println "after")
  (GLFW/glfwTerminate))
```

As before, if I uncomment the `glfwWindowHint` call, there's no problem:

```
$ chmod +x glfw_segfault
$ ./glfw_segfault
before
after
```

If I leave the call out, I get a segfault. This Clojure program has produced a segfault for me more reliably than the C++ program above, but not always. Specifically, when I'm using my integrated Haswell Intel HD Graphics, I don't get a segfault. However, when I use `nvidia-settings` to switch to my NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M running the NVIDIA 367.35 driver, I always get a segfault.

Is this a bug in GLFW, or am I simply using it incorrectly? I find the latter a bit difficult to believe, because according to the documentation for [`glfwTerminate`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__init.html#gaaae48c0a18607ea4a4ba951d939f0901), initializing and terminating the library multiple times is supported:

> Once this function is called, you must again call `glfwInit` successfully before you will be able to use most GLFW functions.

It seems to me that the problem has something to do with the `GLFW_CLIENT_API` window hint, but I can't figure out what it might be. Because this seems to be a bug, I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/819) on GitHub.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem using g++

Comment: @Amadeus Could you try the Clojure program? I added more detailed information to my question about when the segfault appears and when it does not. You can install the Oracle JDK as explained [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) and Boot as explained [here](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot#install).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't want to install those programs just to test this one. You have opened an issue. Let's see what they said.